# How to set width and height of a panel according to the resolution of the user screen?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages, screen-resolution

I have a page which is attached to a masterpage. In this page i have update panel and in it have i have a asp.net panel.

This panel has gridview which shows data from database. Currently I have fixed width and height of the panel. So if user screen resolution is bigger than that specified width and height, then it leaves blank spaces.

I want to avoid this. I have read that we can use javascript to get screen resolution of user screen. I tried this in a page which is not attached to any masterpage and called that javascript function in the body of that page and it worked fine. But i dont know how to do this in a page attached to a masterpage. The code that used is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getWidth(width)
    {
        document.getElementById('Panel1').style.width = width+'px';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:getWidth(screen.width)">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Dotted" Height="50px" Width="125px" ScrollBars="Horizontal">
            </asp:Panel>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you thought about just using css to set the width and height? That way you could just #Panel1{width:100%;height:100%;}

Comment: If i set width and height of panel as 100% then it doesnt gives me scroll bars even if they are set true. Instead it creates a scroll bar in overall page and i dont want that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    }

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
       getWidth(screen.width)
    }

    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function getWidth(width)
    {

        $get('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>').style.width  = width+'px';

    }

</script>
```